# How do I create a step in my SQL Server Agent Job which will run my SSIS package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, ssis

I'm trying to create an automated job for the SQL Server Agent to run. The job is supposed to run my SSIS package.

Here's what I have so far:

```
EXEC sp_add_job @job_name = 'My Job'
            ,@description = 'My First SSIS Job'
            ,@job_id = @jobid OUTPUT

EXEC sp_add_jobstep @job_id =@jobid
                    ,@step_name = N'Upload Data'
                    ,@step_id = 1
                    ,@command=N'/FILE "D:\Installs\Upload.dtsx"'
EXEC sp_add_jobstep @job_id = @jobid
                    ,@step_name = N'Download Data'
                    ,@step_id = 2
                    ,@command=N'/FILE "D:\Installs\Download.dtsx"'
```

Unfortunately when I run this, I get an error saying

> Incorrect syntax near '/'

I suspect it's complaining about the `/FILE` in my command.

I can't find documentation about the appropriate syntax to use within @command anywhere -- I pulled `/FILE` out of some old code I found somewhere.  What is the correct syntax for running an SSIS package in a job?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

I ran the SQL script in the question but didn't encounter any errors. So, I am not sure what is causing the error in your case. However, if you have access to `SQL Server Agent` through SQL Server Management Studio. Here are the steps to create a job using the Graphical User Interface.

1. Go to SQL Server Management Studio. Expand `SQL Server Agent` and right-click on Jobs, then select `New Job...` as shown in screenshot #**1**.
2. Provide a name and Owner by default will be the account that creates the job but you can change it according to your requirements. Assign a Category if you would like to and also provide a description. Refer screenshot #**2**.
3. On the Steps section, click `New...` as shown in screenshot #**3**.
4. On the New Job Step dialog, provide a Step name. Select `SQL Server Inegration Services Package` from Type. This step will run under `SQL Agent Service Account` by default. Select the package source as `File system` and browse to the package path by clicking on ellipsis. This will populate the Package path. Refer screenshot #**4**. If you don't want the step to execute under the **`SQL Agent Service Account`**, then refer the steps #**8** - **9** to know how you can use a different account.
5. If you have a SSIS configuration file (.dtsConfig) for the package, click on the **Configurations** tab and add the Configuration file as shown in screenshot #**5**.
6. Click OK and there is the package in step 1 as shown in screenshot #**6**. Similarly, you can create different steps.
7. Once the job has been created, you can right-click on the job and select `Script Job as --> CREATE To --> New Query Editor Window` to generate the script as shown in  screenshot #**7**.
8. To run the SSIS step under different account, on the Management Studio, navigate to `Security --> right-click on Cedentials --> select New Credential...` as shown in screenshot #**8**.
9. On the `New Credential` dialog, provide a Credential name, Windows account and Password under which you would like to execute SSIS steps in SQL jobs. Refer screenshot #**9**. Credential will be created as shown in screenshot #**10**.
10. Next, we need to create a proxy. On the Management Studio, navigate to `SQL Server Agent --> Proxies --> right-click on SSIS Package Execution --> select New Proxy...` as shown in screenshot #**11**.
11. On the New Proxy Account window, provide a Proxy name, select the newly created Credential, provide a description and select SQL Server Integration Services Package as shown in screenshot #**12**. Proxy account should be created as shown in screenshot #**13**.
12. Now, if you go back to the step in SQL job, you should see the newly created Proxy account in the **Run as** drop down. Refer screenshot #**14**.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

**Screenshot #9:**

[image: 9]

**Screenshot #10:**

[image: 10]

**Screenshot #11:**

[image: 11]

**Screenshot #12:**

[image: 12]

**Screenshot #13:**

[image: 13]

**Screenshot #14:**

[image: 14]

Comment: Thanks Siva, this is the most complete answer to my question.

Comment: If you use Configuration table (`dbo.[SSIS Configuration]`) instead of configuration file (`dtsConfig`), be advise to manually edit the `dtsx` file to specify the connection string directly to the table.

Comment: Can you please provide **Sql Script** for this job creation for SSIS package deployment, to run in client system.. i wnt get access to do manually using wizard

Comment: This is awesome! Since MS decided to delete the old articles and redirect everything to the new SQL server docs this article finally helped me.

Answer (score 9):

If you're building the job using the sp_add... procs, I think you need to explicitly set the subsystem to be called, a la

```
EXEC sp_add_jobstep @job_id = @jobid,
@step_name = N'Upload Data',
@step_id = 1,
@subsystem = 'DTS',
@command=N'/FILE "D:\Installs\Upload.dtsx"'
```

This is equivalent to @Siva's Screenshot #4 'Type'='SQL Server Integration Services Package'.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187358.aspx) MSDN article for the complete list of subsystems.

**EDIT**: 'TSQL' is the default, so your current setup is trying to execute '/FILE "D:\Installs\Upload.dtsx"' as a T-SQL command.

Comment: Thanks Dave, your edit was correct, looks like I was trying to execute '/FILE'