# How do I deploy an SSIS package to run on a schedule as an SQL Server Agent job?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, ssis

I have a few SSIS packages that are built in VS2008 I am trying to set up to run on a schedule with the SQL Server Agent. I am having trouble figuring out how to deploy these. I can run these locally off of a path to my file system but cannot figure out how to deploy to MSDB. Does anyone have an experience doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can deploy the packages to MSDB database or you can place it in a folder on the server to run it from the file system.

While answering the question in the below given link, I tried to provide a step by step instructions of how to create an SQL Server Agent job for a package that I assumed is stored in the location C:\temp on the server.

[How do I create a step in my SQL Server Agent Job which will run my SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712811/how-do-i-create-a-step-in-my-sql-server-agent-job-which-will-run-my-ssis-package/6713464#6713464)

Personally, I feel file system based SSIS package execution to be simpler because once you have the SQL Server Agent job setup, further deployment of the package involves simply moving the dtsx and related dtsConfig files.

However, if you want to apply SQL permissions on who gets access to view or run the package, then probably deploying it to the MSDB database is the option to go.

Following link shows how to deploy a package to MSDB:

[How to Deploy package in MSDB](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/7c819700-a663-488f-8937-c236f43b42f5/)

Hope that gives you an idea.