# How to schedule SSIS packages to run from within an SQL Server agent job?

Tags: ssis, scheduling

I have some task which I want to schedule and I did not work with SSIS before. I have created SSIS package using the Execute T-SQL Statement Task. It has run my procedures from DB.

But I need to run this procedures weekly using SSIS package. Is it possible and how can it be implemented?

Once this is implemented, I will send this SSIS package to the guys who are working with SQL server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible option would be to use an SQL Server Agent job to run the SSIS packages.

Have a look at the following link. It explains how to create an SQL job that can execute an SSIS package on a scheduled basis. You can create a Credential and Proxy if you need to access any external resources outside of the database. If your package accesses only a database, you can possibly skip the steps that create Credential and Proxy Account.

The scheduling part is not explained in the below link but I think it should be easy enough to figure out on the SQL Server Agent Job creation dialog.

[How do I create a step in my SQL Server Agent Job which will run my SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712811/how-do-i-create-a-step-in-my-sql-server-agent-job-which-will-run-my-ssis-package/6713464#6713464)

Hope that gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS package execution scheduling is done on the SSIS server, when the package is imported (or, on the machine you wrote the SSIS package on, if it's the Production machine - it isn't, right?)

The SSIS GUI (BIDS) offers a range of scheduling options.

Comment: SSMS GUI, in particular, SQL Agent offers a rand of scheduling options. BIDS has nothing to do with scheduled invocations