# SSIS Script Task does not see File on network drive

Tags: file, networking, permissions, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

My SSIS package uses `Script Task` which calls `File.Exists()` to determine if file is present.

I have to servers on same domain, e.g. `THISDOMAIN`, `SERVER1` and `SERVER2`

I have user `THISDOMAIN\ADMIN` which is on both servers.

`SERVER1` needs to access `SERVER2` folder `C:\` which is mapped to `SERVER1` as `D:\`

On `SERVER1` there is SQL Server 2008R2 which has SQL Server Agent with Account `THISDOMAIN\ADMIN`

If I log on to SSIS on `SERVER1` with windows authentication as `THISDOMAIN\ADMIN` package executes successfully.

But if I execute the same package with SQL Server Agent, it does not see the network drive `D:\` on 'SERVER1`

What I tried:

- [Why wouldn't SSIS package running in SQL Server Agent job transfer files to a network folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714516/why-wouldnt-ssis-package-running-in-sql-server-agent-job-transfer-files-to-a-ne)
- [How do I create a step in my SQL Server Agent Job which will run my SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712811/how-do-i-create-a-step-in-my-sql-server-agent-job-which-will-run-my-ssis-package)

Comment: Mapped drives get flaky when it comes to service accounts.  The mapping via Windows Explorer generally only works when it's not running as a service.  Is there a reason you don't use UNC paths, which is recommended for situations such as this?

Comment: Just to ensure I have it correct, thisdomain\admin is the account for SQL Agent. You have the credentials to log in as this user and when you do so, you see the drive mapped as D. When you execute your package through SQL Agent it does not see the D drive?

Comment: @billinkc correct, but if I execute manually trough SQL Integrations Server it does see the drive

Comment: @Taegost I will try this but I'm not sure this is the real issue, because manually executing this package it does find this drive.

Comment: And no stored credentials are involved with this, correct?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you run this from the command line as the admin account, does it work? `runas /netonly /user:thisdomain\admin "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\dtexec.exe" /file "C:\path\MyPackage.dtsx"`

Comment: @skmasq - When you say "manually executing", you mean after you log into the server as the user, you can execute it from the admin controls?

Comment: @Taegost Thank you, `UNC` path worked... Really silly thing tbh.

Comment: @skmasq It is, it's kind of an abstract concept to wrap your head around.  I saw it once before at a former job, when we switched to headless services from standard processes, and things stopped working.  Since then, I always use a UNC path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When going across the network to access files/folders, it's always recommended to use the UNC path.

Especially in a situation like this where the drive may be mapped via Windows Explorer and works when you're logged in, but doesn't work when you're trying to access that same path from a service that isn't logged in.