# Unable to create network file executed as sql agent job

Tags: ssis

I created a package that creates a file on a share.

The share has modify permissions for a windows account. I created a job to test the package and I ran the sql agent with that windows account which has permission to the share. If I execute the job the package runs.If I execute the package itself in SSMS the package fails. Is there some permission I am missing?

I added the same windows user that the agent uses to the SSISDB and gave the windows user execute and read on the package and it still fails.

Comment: Are you using a proxy account in sql agent to execute the package?

Comment: Does your user account have the necessary rights to the file share?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289442/which-user-credentials-does-integration-services-catalog-use-to-execute-packages

Comment: Yes I have a windows account set for the proxy account in the SSIS Package Execution folder. In the account properties it is set to the SQL Server Integration Services Package subsystem. The account has a user mapping to the SSISDB database with the public role. It has modify access to the share. This can be verified by running the agent as that user and execute the job associated with the package and it works. What doesn't work is running the package without the job.

Comment: The agent account and my personal account both has modify permissions to the share.

Comment: If I run SSDT and execute the package it runs correctly with my credentials. If I run the package using SSMS it should use my credentials based on the link Ben sent. If that is true then the package should work correctly but it fails because of permissions to the share. When I run it in SSMS it must be using some other credentials.