# SQL Server Agent Job - Pass date and determine if job will run based on Schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server, schedule, sql-server-agent

I need to determine all SQL Server Agent Jobs that will run on a specific date in the future.  Is it possible to determine all jobs that will run on a future date based on its current schedule.

I know I can get the next_run_date value from MSDB..SYSJOBSCHEDULES but need this extended somehow to pass any date in the future.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, with an example? I find it hard to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: Sure.  Say I Have a SQL Server Agent Job that runs every 2nd Tuesday of every Month.  I need a query that takes a date as a parameter and return 1 if it will be run on that date.  So if I pass 12/9/2013 (2nd tuesday of December) a 1 will be returned.  However, if I pass in 12/10/2013 a -1 will be returned

Comment: Please post the script you have written to do this. Also the current result set and expected result set will surely help in getting responses

Comment: I do not have a script... i was wondering if there is a SQL Server system stored procedure that would do this.  This logic has to be implemented somewhere in sql server since it is used to schedule jobs.  There is a system sproc that calculates next_run_date in msdb..sysjobschedules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/peterl/archive/2008/10/10/Keep-track-of-all-your-jobs-schedules.aspx

this outlines exactly what i am looking for

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it , I hope it useful

http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/tutorial/sql_server_agent_jobs.cfm

[How do I create a step in my SQL Server Agent Job which will run my SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712811/how-do-i-create-a-step-in-my-sql-server-agent-job-which-will-run-my-ssis-package)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlagent/archive/2010/10/13/creating-multi-step-sql-agent-job.aspx

http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/ss/sql_server_agent_3.htm

http://bi-polar23.blogspot.in/2008/06/ssis-and-sql-server-agent-choosing.html

Comment: Most of these links reference the process of creating a SQL Server agent job.  I know how to create a job with a defined scheduled.  Unfortunately, these links do not answer my initial question.