# how to create batch file for sql query?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I am using a SQL Server 2008 database. I have these SQL query:

```
update CommonMst set CTypeValue='107' where CommonType='Current OrderNo'
```

I need to create batch file to execute this query every month's 1st date using schedule. How can i get this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create SQL Schedule job to run this every 1st of each month.

Steps to schedule a job. Check this [URL](http://www.dailycoding.com/posts/step_by_step_guide_to_add_a_sql_job_in_sql_server_2005.aspx).

**Note:** In order to keep this task running on every first of the month, you need to be sure that SQL Server Agent is running.

Answer (score 0):

As above said, you need to set schedule for timing in Sql-Jobs via sqlserver agent.

But you need the above version of Sqlserver express. Express version does not have this feature.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187910.aspx

[How do I create a step in my SQL Server Agent Job which will run my SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712811/how-do-i-create-a-step-in-my-sql-server-agent-job-which-will-run-my-ssis-package)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190223%28v=sql.110%29.aspx