# System Scheduler and SSIS execution problems

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, scheduler

I have this issue with the System Scheduler. I have created a project using Visual Studio 2010, then I have scheduled its execution at a certain moment of the day, but when I tried to see the execution result nothing had happened, the execution was never initialized. Just for check I created a very simple package that gets the information from one table to another, but when the execution is running using the scheduler the command window appears so quickly that I could not see nothing and besides the package was not executed.

I wonder if maybe there is a problem with this version of Visual Studio and the scheduler because with 2008 version I have never had any problem, and if there is a possible solution for this problem.

This is what I used to do:

First I create a .bat file with the next code

```
@echo off 
dtexec /FILE "Path_to_my_package\Package.dtsx" /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING EWCDI 
echo Finishing........
exit
```

Then I specify in the System Scheduler that I want to run this package in a certain without any problem, and now this is not working.

Comment: Are you using package deployment or project?  What is the command you are using to execute the package?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't create and schedule a SQL Agent job?

Answer (score 0):

As mmarie said, you should use SQL Agent for automating SSIS packages. The Visual Studio is irrelevant with this issue. If you used the normal scheduler, you should invoke DTExec and pass your package as an argument, you can check the link below for more details:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx

However, the better alternative is SQL Agent, where you can create a job and check the outcome in a better way. It is explained in details in the below link:

[How do I create a step in my SQL Server Agent Job which will run my SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712811/how-do-i-create-a-step-in-my-sql-server-agent-job-which-will-run-my-ssis-package)